# Best way to insert a list of links into a post outside of the_content

Tags: custom-field, list

I would like to have a list of links to PDFs on some posts that sit outside of the main content. See wireframe:
[image: wireframe]

The links need to be editable via the editor / wp admin and be post-specific. It's a custom template so I have full access to the "single.php" template.

Because I need to be able to edit the link text for each link, I don't think I can use custom fields as there is no way to match up two different fields (ie a "link" field and "link_text" field), let alone have multiple "link" and "link_text" fields.

One idea is to hand-write the HTML for the list of links and save it to one custom field, but my client may struggle to add and edit raw HTML.

Any ideas? I'm open to using a plugin, but I can't find a suitable one.

Comment: Are you looking for a [navigation menu](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-navigation-menu-in-wordpress-beginners-guide/)?

Comment: There is a very easy way to do what you want, but that involves using the Advanced Custom Fields Pro plugin. I don't know if you want to use a plugin, but you can place a repeatable custom field, that groups two text fields that you can repeat as many times as you want within the post editor. The text fields will be grouped in pairs, so you can use one for the URL and the other one for the link text.

Comment: @PatJ No, I'm looking for a way to display a list of links on posts that can vary post to post.

Comment: @Laloptk Thank you. I thought I'd have to use something like that.